# Removing a row from multiple rows javascript and jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

My structure is like this

```
Itemid
itemname
itemdescription
itemprice
itemquantity
totalamount.
```

In this structure I have function to calculate the total (price*quantity). I have a add row function that lets add a row and a Grantotal function(adding all the totals). All I need to have is delete function, I have tried deleting the rows in many things but it is not working.

Here is my code:

```
       $(document).ready(function () {


        var counter = 2;

        $("#addButton").click(function () {
            if (counter > 100) {
                alert("Only 100 textboxes allowed");
                return false;
            }

            var newTextBoxDiv = $(document.createElement('tr'))
                .attr("id", 'TextBoxDiv' + counter);

            newTextBoxDiv.after().html('<td class="first"><input placeholder="Item Code ' + counter + '" class="itmcode" type="text" name="data[' + counter + '][0]" id="itemcode' + counter + '" ></td>' + '<td><input class="itmname" placeholder="Item Name ' + counter + '" type="text" name="data[' + counter + '][1]" id="itemname' + counter + '" ></td>' + '<td><input class="itmdesc" placeholder="Item DESC' + counter + '" type="text" name="data[' + counter + '][2]" id="itemdesc' + counter + '" ></td>' + '<td><input class="itmamnt" placeholder="Item AMT' + counter + '" type="text" name="data[' + counter + '][3]" id="itemamnt' + counter + '" /></td>' + '<td><input class="itmqty" placeholder="Item QTY ' + counter + '" type="text" name="data[' + counter + '][4]" id="itemqty' + counter + '" /></td>' + '<td><input type="text" name="total' + counter + '" id="total' + counter + '" class="total" /></td><td><button class="del">Delete</button></td>');

            newTextBoxDiv.appendTo("#TextBoxesGroup");

            counter++;
        });

        $(document).on('keyup', '.itmqty', function (ev) {
            // grab ID to get row number
            thisID = $(this).attr("id");
            rowNum = thisID.slice(-1);

            //get Amount entered
            amt = $('#itemamnt' + rowNum).val();
            //get QTY
            qty = $('#itemqty' + rowNum).val();
            $('#total' + rowNum).val(amt * qty);

            currentCount = counter - 1;
            var tot = 0;
            $('.total').each(function () {
                tot += parseFloat($(this).val());
            });

            $('#running_total').val(tot);
        });

        //$('#total').val($('#itm-qty').val() * $('#itm-amnt').val());
    });

       ('#TextBoxesGroup').on('click','.del', function(){
    if(counter==2){
          alert("No More Rows to Remove");
          return false;
       }   

    counter--;

        $("#TextBoxDiv" + counter).remove();

     });


 // $('#TextBoxesGroup').on('click','.del', function(){
  // $(this).parents('tr:eq(0)').remove();
 // });
```

I have tried this code also:

```
$('#TextBoxesGroup').on('click','.del', function(){
      $(this).parents('tr:eq(0)').remove();
});
```

**HTML**

```
<input type="button" id="addButton" value=" Add Row " />
<table id="TextBoxesGroup">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input id="itemcode1" placeholder="Item Code 1" class="itmcode" />
        </td>
        <td>
            <input id="itemname1" placeholder="Item Name 1" />
        </td>
        <td>
            <input id="itemdesc1" placeholder="Item Description 1" />
        </td>
        <td>
            <input id="itemamnt1" placeholder="Item Amount 1" class="itmamnt" />
        </td>
        <td>
            <input id="itemqty1" placeholder="Item Qty 1" class="itmqty" />
        </td>
        <td>
            <input id="total1" placeholder="Item Total 1" class="total" />
        </td>
        <td><button class="del">Delete</button></td>
    </tr>
</table>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Running Total</td>
        <td>
            <input name="running_total" id="running_total" />
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Please let me know what mistake I made and help me in getting this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fiddle link simplied. few mistake like ('#TextBoxesGroup) here no $ symbol.And brace are not well balanced.

Instead count variable you code will be obsolete so use `$('#TextBoxesGroup tr').length`.

1)

```
   $('#TextBoxesGroup').on('click','.del', function(){
          $(this).closest("tr").remove();
    });
```

2)    Runningtotal value refresh code snippet.

```
 var tot1 = 0;

    $('#TextBoxesGroup tr td input.total').each(function () {           
        tot1 += parseFloat($(this).val());
    });

    $('#running_total').val(tot1);
```

[Working Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/9nEne/28/)

Comment: Thank you Raja ! It is working great. And one thing, when i click the delete button, the #runningtotal should be refreshed. I tried doing this,

Comment: $('#TextBoxesGroup').on('click','.del', function(){
      if($('#TextBoxesGroup tr').length <= 1){
            alert("No More Rows to Remove");
            return false;
       }   
        
        $(this).closest("tr").remove();
  var tot1 = 0;
            $('.total').each(function () {
                tot1 += parseFloat($(this).val());
            });

            $('#running_total').val(tot1);

       // counter--;

       // $("#TextBoxDiv" + counter).remove();

     }); but it is not working.could you please tell me the mistake

Comment: @user3219325 answer updated and jsfiddle link updated take a look.

Comment: Thats Awesome :) worked great ! But could you tell me how this code works ??$('#TextBoxesGroup tr td input.total').each(function ()

Comment: @user3219325 basically it select all input with class name total inside td and it should inside tr which inside out given id #TextBoxesGroup.